# В приложении не отображаются изображения в *.svg

Tags: java, android, svg

Имеется приложение, отображающее определенную информацию о всех странах, используя сайт https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all

Проблема в том, что не отображаются изображения флагов. В LogCat имеется ошибка SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Поменяв на источник с расширением изображении jpg, я понял, что дело в этом.

Как дать понять программе, что svg не враг?

Код:

**BitmapCache**

```
public class BitmapCache extends LruCache < String, Bitmap > implements ImageLoader.ImageCache {
  /**
   * @param maxSize for caches that do not override {@link #sizeOf}, this is
   *                the maximum number of entries in the cache. For all other caches,
   *                this is the maximum sum of the sizes of the entries in this cache.
   */
  public BitmapCache(int maxSize) {
    super(maxSize);
  }

  public BitmapCache() {
    this(getDefaultCacheSize());
  }

  public static int getDefaultCacheSize() {
    final int maxMemory = (int)(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
    final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
    return cacheSize;
  }
  @Override
  protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
    return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024;
  }

  @Override
  public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    return get(url);
  }

  @Override
  public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
    put(url, bitmap);
  }
}
```

**AppController**

```
public class AppController extends Application {
  public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();
  private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
  private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
  private static AppController mInstance;
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
  }
  public static synchronized AppController getmInstance() {
    return mInstance;
  }
  public RequestQueue getmRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
      mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
  }
  public ImageLoader getmImageLoader() {
    getmRequestQueue();
    if (mImageLoader == null) {
      mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue, new BitmapCache());
    }
    return this.mImageLoader;
  }
  public < T > void addToRequesQueue(Request < T > request, String tag) {
    request.setTag((TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag));
    getmRequestQueue().add(request);
  }
  public < T > void addToRequesQueue(Request < T > request) {
    request.setTag(TAG);
    getmRequestQueue().add(request);
  }
  public void cancelPendingRequest(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
      mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
  }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
  private LayoutInflater inflater;
  private Activity activity;
  private List < Item > items;
  ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getmInstance().getmImageLoader();
  public Adapter(Activity activity, List < Item > items) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.items = items;
  }
  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (inflater == null) {
      inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
    }
    if (imageLoader == null)
      imageLoader = AppController.getmInstance().getmImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView imageView = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
    TextView capital = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_capital);
    TextView region = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_region);
    //getting data for row
    Item item = items.get(position);
    imageView.setImageUrl(item.getFlag(), imageLoader);

    name.setText(item.getName());

    capital.setText(String.valueOf(item.getCapital()));
    region.setText(String.valueOf(item.getRegion()));


    return convertView;
  }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private static final String url = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all";
  private ProgressDialog dialog;
  private List < Item > array = new ArrayList < Item > ();
  private ListView listView;
  private Adapter adapter;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
    adapter = new Adapter(this, array);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    dialog.show();


    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener < JSONArray > () {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        hideDialog();
        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
          try {
            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
            Item item = new Item();
            item.setName(obj.getString("name"));
            item.setFlag(obj.getString("flag"));
            item.setCapital(obj.getString("capital"));
            item.setRegion(obj.getString("region"));

            array.add(item);
          } catch (JSONException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
      @Override
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

      }
    });
    AppController.getmInstance().addToRequesQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
  }
  public void hideDialog() {
    if (dialog != null) {
      dialog.dismiss();
      dialog = null;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Формат SVG не поддерживается напрямую Андроидом, можно либо:

1. Через [Android Studio Vector Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html) - переформатировать SVG файлы в `VectorDrawable`
2. Или использовать сторонние либы, их не то чтобы много, но они есть - [например](https://github.com/search?l=Java&q=svg&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

Comment: Удобнее использовать родной конвертор, он сразу покажет возможные ошибки. С либами проблем больше.